# replacing file contents using fwrite

Tags: php

I am trying to write data to a php file everytime the page is refreshed. The code below successfully writes to a file, however, the file contents remain the same after the first rewrite, even though the the data contained in the array that is used to write to the file is different every time the page is refreshed.

My question is: how can I rewrite or replace the contents of .php file that already exists?

I tried `unlink('../html/freesample2.php');` to solve this problem, by deleting the 'written' file and then recreating it, however it did not help.

I appreciate any advice.

```
//Create variable for file I want to write to
//second parameter 'a' stands for APPEND
$f = fopen('../html/freesample2.php', 'a') or die('fopen failed');

$php_script= '<?php $free_sample_array_new = Array(); $free_sample_array_new[] = '.$free_sample_array[0].'; $free_sample_array_new[] = '.$free_sample_array[1].'; ?>';

fwrite($f, $php_script);

fclose($f);
```

Comment: did you have permissions on the file? try to unlink the file and stop the execution, then have a look if the file is deleted or still exists. Or try to use file_exists or is_file to look if the file exists.. to create an absolut path you can use the function realpath()

Comment: As i said in my post, the file is created successfully, that is not the problem. The problem is replacing the file contents of a file that is already created.

Comment: Yes the file gets deleted after using unlink

Comment: Try W - Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Comment: Open the file using w parameter, it will automatically replace your content

Comment: I tried 'w' instead of 'a', it doesn't work... file contents remain the same.

Comment: @MHZ Are you 100% sure the file is changing when you try "w" as type? This sets the file pointer to the beginning of the file so it should overwrite everything.

Comment: I am 100% the file is NOT changing when I add "w" as type and if the file isn't already created, it does not create it (though it should), and with 'a' it creates the file if it isn't created, writes to it once, but does not 'append' new data the second,third,etc.. time around..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to open a file for writing, you can use `'w'` as the access mode for `fopen()`. That will create the file if it's not there yet, or truncate it to be empty and you can write into it as if it's new.

Alternatively you can use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to make the operation a oneliner.

*side note:* If you are generating php code with literal values, take a look into [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) function, that could simplify it vastly (with the second, optional parameter).

Comment: I tried 'w' instead of 'a', it doesn't work... file contents remain the same.

Comment: Could it be that you are writing the same values into a file as the old ones in it already and that's why it doesn't seem to be changing? Check the file's mtime with, or the inode number of your file with `ls -i` if you are on a unix like system, and see if its changing.

Comment: im running windows:/ also I am using print_r to print out free_smaple _array array contents, which are unique on every refresh...

Answer (score 0):

Run this code and check if each time after refresh, freesample2.php has new value or not?

```
<?
$free_sample_array = array(rand());
$f = fopen('../html/freesample2.php', 'w') or die('fopen failed');
$php_script= '<?php $free_sample_array_new = Array(); $free_sample_array_new[] = '.$free_sample_array[0].'; ?>';
fwrite($f, $php_script);
fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: I am using print_r to print out  free_smaple _array array contents, which are unique on every refresh, so this isn't the problem. Thanks anyways though.

Comment: And when you open in append, are new lines (even if they contain same data) getting written to the end of the file?

Comment: seems like some weird permission issue, check $f before writing, to see if it is giving a resource id or if is returning false?

$f = fopen("..");
if(!$f) 
 die("Could not open file"); 
else 
 //write to file

Comment: if the file doesn't exist it does not create it... if it exists nothing happens (while using 'w')...

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, you must close the csv file (if opened on desktop), before writing it with 'w' mode.